# boost condition variable issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio, boost-thread

The following minimal code sample of a larger program sends commands from client threads to an asio io_service object. The io_service object (in the Ios class) is being run with one thread. When the command is sent the client thread waits until it is notified by  the **Ios** object (via Cmd::NotifyFinish()) that it is completed.

This sample seems to run on Linux Ubuntu 11.04 with boost 1.46 fine but on Windows 7 boost 1.46 it asserts.

I suspect it is something to do with the lock in Cmd::NotifyFinish(). When I move the lock out of the nested scope so that when waitConditionVariable_.notify_one() is called in the lock's scope it doesn't crash on Windows 7. However, the boost::thread documentation states that notify_one() doesn't need to be called within the lock.

The stack trace (below) shows it is asserting when notify_one() is called. It is as though the cmd object has disappeared before notify is called...

How do I make this thread safe and not assert?

```c
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/locks.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/condition_variable.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class Cmd
{
public:
    Cmd() :   cnt_(0), waitPred_(false), waiting_(false)
    {
    }
    virtual ~Cmd()
    {
    }
    void BindInfo(int CmdSeq)
    {
        cnt_ = CmdSeq;
    }
    void NotifyFinish()
    {
        // call by service thread...
        {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(waitMutex_);
            waitPred_ = true;
            if (!waiting_)
            {
                // don't need to notify as isn't waiting
                return;
            }
        }
        waitConditionVariable_.notify_one();
    }
    void Wait()
    {
        // called by worker threads
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(waitMutex_);
        waiting_ = true;
        while (!waitPred_)
            waitConditionVariable_.wait(lock);
    }
    int cnt_;
private:

    boost::mutex waitMutex_;
    boost::condition_variable waitConditionVariable_;
    bool waitPred_;
    bool waiting_;
};


class Ios
{
public:
    Ios() : timer_(ios_), cnt_(0), thread_(boost::bind(&Ios::Start, this))
    {
    }
    void Start()
    {
        timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
        timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&Ios::TimerHandler, this, _1));
        ios_.run();
    }
    void RunCmd(Cmd& C)
    {
        ios_.post(boost::bind(&Ios::RunCmdAsyn, this, boost::ref(C)));
    }

private:
    void RunCmdAsyn(Cmd& C)
    {
        C.BindInfo(cnt_++);
        C.NotifyFinish();
    }
    void TimerHandler(const boost::system::error_code& Ec)
    {
        if (!Ec)
        {
            std::cout << cnt_ << "\n";
            timer_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
            timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&Ios::TimerHandler, this, _1));
        }
        else
            exit(0);
    }

    boost::asio::io_service ios_;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer_;
    int cnt_;
    boost::thread thread_;
};

static Ios ios;

void ThreadFn()
{
    while (1)
    {
        Cmd c;
        ios.RunCmd(c);
        c.Wait();
        //std::cout << c.cnt_ << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Starting\n";
    boost::thread_group threads;
    const int num = 5;

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        // Worker threads
        threads.create_thread(ThreadFn);
    }
    threads.join_all();

}
```

*stack trace*

```
msvcp100d.dll!std::_Debug_message(const wchar_t * message, const wchar_t * file, unsigned int line)  Line 15    C++
iosthread.exe!std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry>,std::allocator<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry> > > >::_Compat(const std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry>,std::allocator<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry> > > > & _Right)  Line 238 + 0x17 bytes   C++
iosthread.exe!std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry>,std::allocator<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry> > > >::operator==(const std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry>,std::allocator<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry> > > > & _Right)  Line 203 C++
iosthread.exe!std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry>,std::allocator<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry> > > >::operator!=(const std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry>,std::allocator<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry> > > > & _Right)  Line 208 + 0xc bytes C++
iosthread.exe!std::_Debug_range2<std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry>,std::allocator<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry> > > > >(std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry>,std::allocator<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry> > > > _First, std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry>,std::allocator<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry> > > > _Last, const wchar_t * _File, unsigned int _Line, std::random_access_iterator_tag __formal)  Line 715 + 0xc bytes  C++
iosthread.exe!std::_Debug_range<std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry>,std::allocator<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry> > > > >(std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry>,std::allocator<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry> > > > _First, std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry>,std::allocator<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry> > > > _Last, const wchar_t * _File, unsigned int _Line)  Line 728 + 0x6c bytes    C++
iosthread.exe!std::find_if<std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry>,std::allocator<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry> > > >,bool (__cdecl*)(boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry> const &)>(std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry>,std::allocator<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry> > > > _First, std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry>,std::allocator<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry> > > > _Last, bool (const boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry> &)* _Pred)  Line 92 + 0x54 bytes    C++
iosthread.exe!std::remove_if<std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry>,std::allocator<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry> > > >,bool (__cdecl*)(boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry> const &)>(std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry>,std::allocator<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry> > > > _First, std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry>,std::allocator<boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry> > > > _Last, bool (const boost::intrusive_ptr<boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry> &)* _Pred)  Line 1848 + 0x58 bytes    C++
iosthread.exe!boost::detail::basic_condition_variable::notify_one()  Line 267 + 0xb4 bytes  C++
iosthread.exe!Cmd::NotifyFinish()  Line 41  C++
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the condition variable is a member of the `Cmd` object that is created by the client thread and is destroyed by that client thread when the wait is completed.

So you have a race condition where:

- `boost::condition_variable::notify_one()` is called on the 'service thread'
- that unblocks the client thread that's waiting on that condition variable
- the client thread can then destroy the condition variable that the service thread is still working with in its call to `notify_one`.

So your observation that it's "as though the `cmd` object has disappeared before notify is called" is pretty much exactly what's happened, I think.  Except that the `Cmd` object didn't disappear before `notify_one()` is called, it disappeared while `notify_one()` was doing its work. Your other note that "the `boost::thread` documentation states that `notify_one()` doesn't need to be called within the lock" is true, but that doesn't mean that the condition variable can be destroyed before `notify_one()` has returned.

You need to manage the lifetime of the `Cmd` object so that the service thread is done using it before it gets destroyed - holding the mutex that's in the `Cmd` object while `notify_one()` is called is one way to do that (as you've noticed).  Or you can pull the condition variable out of the `Cmd` object so that its lifetime is independent of the `Cmd` object (maybe `shared_ptr<>` can help with that).

Also, note that I believe that the `waiting_` member of the `Cmd` class is superfluous - you can call `notify_one()` or `notify_all()`  when there are no waiters on a condition variable - it's already doing the checking for that for you (I don't think it's hurting anything, just that it's complexity that doesn't need to be in the `Cmd` class).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michael. Won't moving the lock in NotifyFinish() to the outer scope force notify_one() to be called before Wait() has exited, because waitConditionVariable_.wait obtains the lock after finishing? So there are two scenarios that Wait can exit. Either when Notify obtains the lock before Wait obtains it or when Wait obtains the lock first and then the condition variable is notified. I agree that the waiting_ memory seems superfluous.

Comment: @Liam: assuming that the change has been made so `NotifyFinish()` holds the mutex while it calls `notify_one()`, then  in your first scenario where `NotifyFinish()` gets called first, it'll grab the mutex, set `waitPred_ = true`, then call `notify_one()` (which will do nothing). All of that will happen before `Wait()` gets a chance to do anything, because if it tries it'll be blocked waiting to acquire the mutex. Once `NotifyFinish()` releases the mutex, the `Wait()` call will be able to proceed; it'll notice that `waitPred_` is `true` and won't bother calling `condition_variable::wait()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
void ThreadFn()
{
    while (1)
    {
        Cmd c;
        ios.RunCmd(c);
         c.Wait();
        //std::cout << c.cnt_ << "\n";
    }
}
```

Since this loop is infinite why not just put Cmd c; outside the scope of the while(1) so it reuses 'c' each iteration of while(1) ?

```
void ThreadFn()
{
    Cmd c;

    while (1)
    {   
        ios.RunCmd(c);
        c.Wait();
        //std::cout << c.cnt_ << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: The code was just an extrapolation of a larger program to demonstrate the problem. There were many different types of commands initialised in the constructor, and also there was no while(1) loop.