# Cancelling boost asio deadline timer safely

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, timer, boost-asio

I'm trying to cancel a `boost::asio::basic_waitable_timer<std::chrono::steady_clock>` safely.

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047765/atomically-cancel-asio-asynchronious-timer-from-another-thread), this code should do that work:

```
timer.get_io_service().post([&]{timer.cancel();})
```

I'm afraid it doesn't work for me.
Am I doing something wrong?
This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/asio.hpp"
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <random>

boost::asio::io_service io_service;
boost::asio::basic_waitable_timer<std::chrono::steady_clock> timer(io_service);
std::atomic<bool> started;

void handle_timeout(const boost::system::error_code& ec)
{
    if (!ec) {
        started = true;
        std::cerr << "tid: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << ", handle_timeout\n";
        timer.expires_from_now(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
        timer.async_wait(&handle_timeout);
    } else if (ec == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) {
        std::cerr << "tid: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << ", handle_timeout aborted\n";
    } else {
        std::cerr << "tid: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << ", handle_timeout another error\n";
    }
}

int main() {

    std::cout << "tid: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << ", Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 100);

    for (auto i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {

        started = false;
        std::thread t([&](){

            timer.expires_from_now(std::chrono::milliseconds(0));
            timer.async_wait(&handle_timeout);

            io_service.run();
        });

        while (!started) {};
        auto sleep = dis(gen);
        std::cout << "tid: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << ", i: " << i << ", sleeps for " << sleep << " [ms]" << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(sleep));
        timer.get_io_service().post([](){
            std::cerr << "tid: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << ", cancelling in post\n";
            timer.cancel();
        });
//      timer.cancel();
        std::cout << "tid: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << ", i: " << i << ", waiting for thread to join()" << std::endl;
        t.join();
        io_service.reset();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

> ...
>   tid: 140737335076608, handle_timeout
>   tid: 140737335076608, handle_timeout
>   tid: 140737353967488, i: 2, waiting for thread to join()
>   tid: 140737335076608, cancelling in post
>   tid: 140737335076608, handle_timeout aborted
>   tid: 140737353967488, i: 3, sleeps for 21 [ms]
>   tid: 140737335076608, handle_timeout
>   tid: 140737353967488, i: 3, waiting for thread to join()
>   tid: 140737335076608, handle_timeout
>   tid: 140737335076608, cancelling in post
>   tid: 140737335076608, handle_timeout
>   tid: 140737335076608, handle_timeout
>   tid: 140737335076608, handle_timeout
>   tid: 140737335076608, handle_timeout
>   tid: 140737335076608, handle_timeout
>   ...
>   continue forever...

As you can see, the `timer.cancel()` is being called from the appropriate thread:

> tid: 140737335076608, cancelling in post

BUT there's no

> tid: 140737335076608, handle_timeout aborted

Afterwards.

Main waits forever.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The cancellation *is* safe.

It's just not robust. You didn't account for the case when the timer wasn't pending. You cancel it once, then, but it will just start a new async wait once the completion handler is invoked.

What follows is my detailed steps on how I traced the issue.

> ***SUMMARY*** TL;DR
>
> Cancelling a time only cancels asynchronous operations in flight.
>
> If you want to shutdown an asynchronous call chain, you'll have to use additional logic for that. An example is given below.

### Handler Tracking

Enabling with

```
#define BOOST_ASIO_ENABLE_HANDLER_TRACKING 1
```

This produces output that can be visualized with `boost/libs/asio/tools/handlerviz.pl`:

### A successful trace

[image]

As you can see, the `async_wait` is in-flight when the cancellation happens.

### A "bad" trace

(truncated because it would run infinitely)

[image]

Note how the completion handler sees `cc=system:0`, not `cc=system:125` (for `operation_aborted`). This is a symptom of the fact that the posted cancel did not actually "take". The only logical explanation (not visible in the diagram) is that the timer had already expired before the cancel gets invoked.

Let's compare the raw traces¹

[image]

¹ removing the noisy difference

#### Detecting It

So, we have a lead. Can we detect it?

```
    timer.get_io_service().post([](){
        std::cerr << "tid: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << ", cancelling in post\n";
        if (timer.expires_from_now() >= std::chrono::steady_clock::duration(0)) {
            timer.cancel();
        } else {
            std::cout << "PANIC\n";
            timer.cancel();
        }
    });
```

Prints:

```
tid: 140113177143232, i: 0, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 1, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 2, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 3, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 4, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 5, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 6, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 7, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 8, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 9, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 10, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 11, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 12, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 13, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 14, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 15, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 16, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 17, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 18, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 19, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 20, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 21, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 22, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 23, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 24, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 25, waiting for thread to join()
tid: 140113177143232, i: 26, waiting for thread to join()
PANIC
```

Could we communicate the "super-cancellation" in another, clearer way? We have ... just the `timer` object to work with, of course:

#### Signaling Shutdown

The `timer` object doesn't have a lot of properties to work with. There's no `close()` or similar, like on a socket, that can be used to put the timer in some kind of invalid state.

However, there's the expiry timepoint, and we can use a special domain 
value to signal "invalid" for our application:

```
timer.get_io_service().post([](){
    std::cerr << "tid: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << ", cancelling in post\n";
    // also cancels:
    timer.expires_at(Timer::clock_type::time_point::min());
});
```

This "special value" is easy to handle in the completion handler:

```
void handle_timeout(const boost::system::error_code& ec)
{
    if (!ec) {
        started = true;
        if (timer.expires_at() != Timer::time_point::min()) {
            timer.expires_from_now(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
            timer.async_wait(&handle_timeout);
        } else {
            std::cerr << "handle_timeout: detected shutdown\n";
        }
    } 
    else if (ec != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) {
        std::cerr << "tid: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << ", handle_timeout error " << ec.message() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks!  
You wrote `The cancellation is safe.` - You meant using `post()`, right?
Not ordinary `timer.cancel()` ?

Comment: Indeed. Is thread safe, in that it doesn't cause a data race, so that behaviour is defined

Comment: Nice workaround, but... don't you think there should be better cancellation function that hides all this mess in its implementation detail? Cancellation-related questions arise again and again...

Comment: @IgorR. I guess I'd love a timer with a `close()` function like I describe. It shouldn't be hard to write one aggregating Asio's timers. In practice I usually have a separate "shutdown" flag/refcount so that I don't have this issue.

Comment: @sehe, I want to have a rule of thumb; According to deadline_timer doc, shared object between threads isn't safe. Are you saying `cancel()` is thread safe specifically because its implementation? When I'm writing a `stop()` function which will stop things like `deadline_timer`/`socket`/`stream descriptor`/`signal`, should I use `post()` as a rule of thumb, in order to prevent undefined behaviour when different threads is calling this `stop()`, or all of this calls should be thread safe, as `cancel()` is? Thanks

Comment: @hudac I'm just confirming that your use of it is threadsafe, I didn't actually say anything else. Your use of it is safe __because__ you post it to the service __and__ the service runs on a single thread, meaning you get "implicit strand" behaviour (no two handlers ever run at the same time).

Comment: @hudac More specifically, that's not a rule of thumb once you run the service on more threads! In that case you need a strand to synchronize access to the service objects (like `deadline_timer`). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794107/why-do-i-need-strand-per-connection-when-using-boostasio/12801042#12801042. I hope this drives home the point that `cancel()` is **not** thread safe, as per the documentation (nobody said this).

Comment: @sehe, do you have workaround such as this for cancelling `boost::asio::signal_set` safely? Or should I use some `shutdown` flag?

Comment: @hudac I don't think I do (I usually just listen for INT/TERM once). You could of course simply [`signal_set.clear(...);`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference.html#boost_asio.reference.basic_signal_set.clear.overload1) (now when you get the signal 0, this means you should probably shutdown)

Comment: How about wrap handle_timeout by strand and post timer.cancel () in same strand