# Implementing readers-writer lock in boost.asio with writer prioritization

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, synchronization, asio

My application handle 3 types of tasks that are originated by either async external source (User press button), or internally (timeout expires, ongoing task trigger another tasks, network event, etc).

Each of the tasks above is characterized by a long waiting period (i.e. sending network request or waiting for network response), in which it can cooperatively suspended and move to another task.

Also, each task (regardless the type) uses a new connection for a single send-and-receive operation.

```
http::response<http::dynamic_body> resp;
boost::beast::http::request<boost::beast::http::string_body> req;
boost::beast::flat_buffer buf; 

http::async_write(stream, req, yield);
http::async_read(stream, buf, resp, yield);
```

I wish to execute all those tasks from the same group of threads that runs the same basic io_context. Here's the relevant code :

```
boost::thread_group threads;
num_threads = 0; 
for(; num_threads < kMaxThreads ; num_threads++) {
   threads.create_thread([] {
      try {
        io_context_.run();
      } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        print("exception found");
      }
   });
}
```

Task description:

- Type1: sending a regular https requests with Authorization header that contain some pre-obtained OAuth2 access token - those tasks can run in parallel so I call them from spawn/io_context:

  ```
  boost::asio::io_context io_context_;


  boost::asio::spawn(io_context_, [](const boost::asio::yield_context &yield) { ... }
  ```
- Type2: is Oauth2 based task to refresh the access token and get a new token in return where the older one gets invalidated.

  This task must be executed serially, since during its execution, we cannot know if it was already reached the server and the old token was invalidated or not.

  Another reason, I can decide to reconnect to another server, so I want to postpone other tasks until I get the token for that server.
- Type3: sending http requests without token so they can be executed in parallel to both the first 2 types.

The ideal way to implement Type2 is by using post/strand without async actions (yield)

```
boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type> strand_

// initialization in class c'tor
strand_(io_context_.get_executor())

boost::asio::post(strand_, []() {...}
```

However, since my network API is using coroutines, and in order to allow type 3 tasks to run, I need to use spawn/strand, but somehow prevent type 2 tasks from entering the queue. So my first Question is how to implement it properly ?

with the current implementation, I'm guaranteed that tasks from the first type, will be executed in parallel, while the second type will be executed alone, and all pending tasks will be waiting for its termination.

Now I want to prioritize the second tasks, so once such task enter the queue, it will enter first, after all currently executing tasks are terminated. Is the any way to do it using boost.asio ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your story is missing a party.

E.g. "I've got 3 types of tasks": even rephrasing to the less anthropocentric "there are 3 types of tasks" or "the application causes 3 types of tasks", the question rising in my mind is: "who is causing the tasks".

Another angle where this pops back up (and not for the first time) is when you describe Type3 tasks: *"Type3: sending http requests without token so they can be executed in parallel to both the first 2 types"* - the quiet omission is *what ties these tasks to your application anyways*.

I have a feeling that the answer is more than "nothing at all" (though Type3 seems like it might be close? Who knows). Specifically, it Type2 inhibits Type1 from proceeding, surely that is on the basis of a authentication "session" (or whatever you name a token lifecycle).

Now, everything could be simple in that there's only one instance of such a session and therefore the authentication token/connection endpoint are a singleton to your application domain. However, usually the picture is that an application handles multiple sessions.

---

Regardless of whether the session is singleton or not, your domain model will require you to acknowledge it, lest you run into heaps of accidental complexity (as it seems you are already discovering).

You could then give your session the ability to queue messages, distinguishing between those requiring authentication and those not requiring authentication. Then when the application logic determines it comes time to refresh/replace the authentication/endpoint tuple, it could

- set a flag to pause initiation of authenticated (Type1) requests
- asynchronously await all pending those requests to complete,
- perform the re-auth request (Type2)
- reset the flag to resume initiation of authenticated requests

There are quite a number of possible approaches to implementing this logic, ranging from (but not limited to) a

- a scheduling strand for Type[12], using a collection of shared state variables and counters to keep track of the place in the session lifecycle
- separate queues and microservices (as coros) servicing them
- a fullblown FSM model (this might be the most test and maintenance friendly approach if you can get it right)

### Events?

However you choose to implement it, you will want a primitive that allows you to post a continuation in response to an application-specific *Event*.

This can usually be modeled using an Asio timer object. E.g. an "infinite" timer can serve as a manual-reset event (e.g. in the Type1 consumer strand `cancel()` it to signal the last pending Type1 request was just completed).

The timer interfaces have a dual interface that allows you to manually cause completion of waits, or *"resumption of waiters"*:

> | Method | Description |
> | --- | --- |
> | `cancel` | Cancel any asynchronous operations that are waiting on the timer. |
> | `cancel_one` | Cancels one asynchronous operation that is waiting on the timer. |

Note that for robustness you might use something like `expires_at(clock_type::timepoint::min())` instead of `cancel()` to make it easier to reliably detect edge-cases (see [Cancelling boost asio deadline timer safely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43168199/cancelling-boost-asio-deadline-timer-safely/43169596#43169596)).

### Summary/Misc

I hope this gives you some ideas to progress your design. Some loose change at the closing gate:

> **Q.** Now I want to prioritize the second tasks, so once such task enter the queue, it will enter first, after all currently executing tasks are terminated. Is the any way to do it using boost.asio ?

There are some examples that show how to make prioritized handlers, with varying levels of elegance:

- https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/invocation/prioritised_handlers.cpp
- https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp14/executors/priority_scheduler.cpp

I'd urge you to focus on modeling your application domain first. Then if an existing tool fits, you can employ it. Otherwise, always prefer to code your core business to your needs.

---

### BONUS TAKE

It just occurred to me that a natural way to model things would be to let the scheduler freely pick up any task. However, as a necessary step in your Type1 coro, you would asynchronously request an up-to-date authentication token:

```
 auto token = session->get_current_auth_token(yield);
```

Now, you can model the Type2 a bit like this:

```
 invalidate_current_auth_token();
 session_idle.async_wait(yield);
 
 auto new_token = async_request_new_token(yield);
 set_current_auth_token(new_token);
```

Where `session_idle` could be a timer object as previously described. The `set_current_auth_token` could use an other timer object to signal token readiness *or* perhaps [use an `experimental::promise`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/composition/promises.html)?

> Disclaimer: I have no experience using those.

Comment: Added an afterburner approach that feels like it might be less heavy than a FSM while avoiding bug-prone state as in the other implementation approaches. Look for the "BONUS TAKE" section near the bottom.

Comment: Hi, I've phrased my questions based on your comments. thanks !

Comment: You said, `However, usually the picture is that an application handles multiple sessions`. can you explain what does the term `session` means ? does it stands for a network connection or task ?

Comment: I should have tried to give more potential names... Session, Arena, Match, Realm, Market, Server, Room, Broker, Channel... I don't have psychic abilities. You know you application domain and know what groups the requests that you need to coordinate. Therefore only you can name the entities in your application domain. In fact I would not be surprised if you actually need two levels (e.g. both different "endpoints" AND "connections"). Then you might find that you needed a third entity to coordinate those two (e.g. a RequestBroker, Router or scheduler).I'm mostly trying to prompt design questions

Comment: The hints in how you can realize these still apply in general