# Maximum wait time of boost::asio::steady_timer

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-timer

How to set maximum waiting time of `boost::asio::steady_timer` in milliseconds?

- When I set `boost::asio::chrono::milliseconds::max()` than timer returns immediately (why?).
- When I set relatively short time, e.g: `boost::asio::chrono::milliseconds(5000)`, the timer waits as expected.

I've configured the timer as written in [boost::asio::steady_timer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/steady_timer.html#boost_asio.reference.steady_timer.examples) documentation:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>

void steadyTimerBlockingWait()
{
    boost::asio::io_context io;
    boost::asio::steady_timer timer(io);

    // Case (1)
    timer.expires_after(boost::asio::chrono::milliseconds::max());

    // Case (2)
    // timer.expires_after(boost::asio::chrono::milliseconds(5000));

    std::cout << "Waiting begin." << std::endl;
    timer.wait();
    std::cout << "Waiting done." << std::endl;
}
```

Case (1)
The `boost::asio::chrono::milliseconds::max().count()` returns `9223372036854775807` on my computer, so I expect the timer to wait for that amount of time.
It finishes immediately without any error instead.

Case (2)
Timer waits 5 seconds as expected.

I need to make the application deterministic and stable, so:

- How to determine maximum amount of time in milliseconds when timer waits correctly?
- Or, How do detect that given time is incorrect?
- Or, Is there a better boost timer implementation that is secure against such misuse?
- By the way, is it possible to set the timer to wait indefinitely (it is not the main question)?

Environment: `Debian 11 (bullseye)`, `64-bit`, Boost `1.81`, gcc `10.2.1`.

Comment: What happens with `max() - 1`? Although it's not documented in the `expires_after` function, max values are often used as flags, ie to turn the counter off. Maybe that's the case here. (I've found that a lot of the `asio` library isn't particularly well documented, and that you often have to read the sources to find out what it going on.)

Comment: @JamesKanze that's something that _users_ of the library often do (because it's so useful to have see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43169596/85371). There are no special values for the awaitable timer services per se

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`expires_after(duration)`](https://github.com/boostorg/asio/blob/73bf97adc8a7f755f5997b08951c284c2eb10b4b/include/boost/asio/detail/deadline_timer_service.hpp#L218) is basically just `expires_at(now() + duration)`.

With a duration of `boost::asio::chrono::milliseconds::max()` the calculation likely overflows to a time in the past so the timer triggers immediately.

To set a timer to never expire you should use:

```
timer.expires_at( decltype( timer )::time_point::max() );
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't expect that boost functions are not protected against range overflow and it is not documented in timer's source code.

Comment: @MichałJaroń there's no reason to pay the cost of the protection, normal code shouldn't ever be going anywhere near the limits

Comment: the standard library has similar behaviour: https://godbolt.org/z/K8h7djrs4

Comment: Yeah that's the point: it's not an Asio feature at all. You're free to use different clock/traits with its `basic_waitable_timer` template